# Get min and max between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm querying the following code, to get min, max and avg, but still give me a problem, because it query all rows that I have from `name = 'Jose'` and not the min, max, and avg.

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATA, 120) AS DATA, 
MIN([VALUE]) AS MinValue, 
AVG([VALUE]) AS MedValue, 
MAX([VALUE]) AS MaxValue
FROM databasename
WHERE (name = 'Jose')
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATA, 120)
ORDER BY DATA ASC
```

Example of what I get from the first query:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFAOm.png) (can't embed image)

To query two dates, I'm using the following code but it don't get any result from query.

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATA, 120) AS DATA, 
MIN([VALUE]) AS MinValue, 
AVG([VALUE]) AS MedValue, 
MAX([VALUE]) AS MaxValue
FROM databasename
WHERE [DATA] between '2017-02-01' AND '2018-03-10' AND name = 'Jose'
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATA, 120)
ORDER BY DATA ASC
```

I'm using MSSQL database.

UPDATE:
I already can query between two dates, as you can see in the second query. Problem that I'm not getting only min, max and avg.
Image:

[image: Query]

Comment: Try seeing the result of `SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), 2017-02-20, 120)` and you will see why it doesn't retrieve data. Never use dates as strings.

Comment: Ups, failed in this one. I changed to date as well, without convert but it query all my data and not min, max and avg

Comment: For your second query, you need to put quotes around your dates.

Comment: @AntonioJose do you want average, max and min value for each date? Between  ` '2017-02-01' AND '2018-03-10' `

Answer (score 0):

try this SQL Query Convert(DATE,'2017-02-01').

```
SELECT DATA AS DATA, 
MIN([VALUE]) AS MinValue, 
AVG([VALUE]) AS MedValue, 
MAX([VALUE]) AS MaxValue
FROM databasename
WHERE [DATA] between CONVERT(DATE, '2017-02-01') AND CONVERT(DATE, '2018-03-10') 
  AND name = 'Jose'
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, '2017-02-20')
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, '2017-02-20') ASC
```

Answer (score -2):

can you consider small change in your query

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATA, 120) AS DATA,
MIN([VALUE]) AS MinValue,
AVG([VALUE]) AS MedValue,
MAX([VALUE]) AS MaxValue
FROM databasename
WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATA, 120) between CONVERT(CHAR(10), 2017 - 02 - 20, 120) AND
CONVERT(CHAR(10), 2018 - 02 - 25, 120) AND name = 'Jose'
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATA, 120)
ORDER BY DATA ASC
```

Comment: Do you know the poor performance of doing this  WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATA, 120) ? SQL Server will have to convert each and every single row and then do the comparison.

Comment: @DawoodAwan as it isn't stated in what format DATA is storing dates what else we could suggest. the issue is not about performance its about not getting results. suggestions are appreciated. thank you

Comment: `CONVERT(CHAR(10), 2017 - 02 - 20, 120)` actually returns the varchar value `1995`, because it's 2017 minus 2 minus 20 (missing string quotes) and it's not what the OP is looking for.